# Workbench Moderation - intermittent save / autosave without new revision

Tags: workbench

I'm stuck with a problem while using **workbench moderation**. while working on a node, my client wants to save / auto save his work but if he hits the default save button then it is creating a **revision** (which is unwanted, since his work is not finished yet).

how is it possible for admin to save their content while they are still working on it, something like "**save as draft**", which they can continue later?

is there a way in **workbench moderation** to have it create a revision only when the moderation state is changed? If not, is there any other module which works with workbench to **auto save / save** the work without creating a new revision.

I also need the admin to stay on the same edit page when he hits this save button. I tested "**save & edit**" module, which does what I need but it also creates a new revision, which is not required.

please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using these modules :

[Save Draft](https://www.drupal.org/project/save_draft)

> Save Draft adds a 'Save as Draft' Button to the node_form for content
>   types, allowing the user to click the 'Save as Draft' button to save
>   the node as a draft.

[Draft](https://www.drupal.org/project/draft)

> The Draft module provides the ability too create drafts of existing
>   nodes as well as new nodes before you have saved them.
>
> The module utilizes the jquery.fields plugin to serialize all of the
>   information and then the information is stored in a database row
>   serialized.
>
> The module provides the ability to **autosave** the content without
>   the user having to hit the Save as Draft button on the form.

Comment: thanks Adi, but my major concern is, I don't want new revisions to be created by workbench, is there a way to avoid that while using the draft module for autosave?